# How tall is Jake the dog when stretched to his full length

Tags: adventure-time

[image: Jake the Dog]

How far can Jake the dog stretch?

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Answer (score 3):

There was a discussion of this [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/do-jakes-powers-have-any-real-limitation), which concluded that, based on the episode, *[The Limit](https://www.moddb.com/groups/adventure-time-community-group/videos/adventure-time-the-limit)*, there is a limit, based on conservation of mass, although the exact limitation is not known, and Jake keeps pushing past that limit when driven to it.

As per [the wiki](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Jake):

> In the episode "The Limit," Jake's Stretchy Powers are put to the test. It is revealed that while Jake can stretch his body to incredible lengths, he does have a limit. As he approaches this limit, his body becomes dangerously thin. Once his mass is distributed along a certain length of his body, it becomes difficult for him to support himself; at one point, Jake was forced to walk along the ground. If he were to stretch beyond his absolute limit, it is presumed that he would completely thin out and die.

Jake himself may not know his limits. From [an interview with Pen Ward](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOLjpUaHfbI&feature=fvwrel) in 2013, in regards to the extent of Jake's powers:

> "I don't think he really know, he's just kinda lazy about it."

So, long story short, there are likely limits, but they're not specified in the show.